# How to sort the list of all possible 3-tuples of elements from list constrained by a condition?

Tags: sorting

I want to know if there's a way to impose desired condition on `Tuple` command output. I have generated a list of 3-tuple of elements from {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} using

```
Tuples[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 3]
```

Now, I want to select only those tuples of the list which satisfy this condition:- a+b+c=15, where a,b and c belongs to {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

I have just begun using Mathematica 10.1.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answer to your original question, sorting only those tuples that are have total sum of 15. You can have a delayed replacement rule with a condition for the required sum:

```
Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 3] /. x_List /; Total[x] == 15 :> Sort[x]
```

If you actually meant selecting only those tuples, you can simply use `Select`:

```
Select[Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 3], Total[#] == 15 &]
```

... or use `Cases`, if you prefer pattern-matching instead of a function:

```
Cases[Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 3], x_List /; Total[x] == 15]
```

One has to note that these are really not scalable methods, since combinatorial explosion will use away all the memory for storage of tuples very easily on larger values. They're straight-forward for very small toy problems, though.

Comment: It solved my problem. 
Thank you.

Comment: May I know what modification should be made if I change the condition to say - **a^2+b^2+c^2=15** ?

Comment: @AbhijitGupta You can easily modify the condition to something like `{a_, b_, c_} /; a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 15` (although 15 doesn't return tuples). You should also consider constructs like `{a, b, c} /. 
 Solve[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 38 && 1 <= a <= b <= c <= 10, {a, b, c}, 
  Integers]`, where you avoid generating tuples to filter altogether.

Answer (score 5):

Horribly inefficient way to do such things. Use `IntegerPartitions`:

```
set = Range@100;
total = 400

s = Select[Tuples[set, 3], Total[#] == t &]; // Timing // First
j = Sort[Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[total, {3}, set]]; // Timing // First

s == j

(* 
   12.948083
   0.
   True
*)
```

The latter is below timing resolution...

For your case, this w/b

```
Sort[Join@@Permutations/@IntegerPartitions[15,{3},{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]]
```

Comment: What modification do I have to make if I change the constraint to 
**a^2+b^2+c^2=40** ?

Comment: @AbhijitGupta: Modify your thinking? Why would one want to create a slew of tuples, most of which won't meet the criteria, only to waste time filtering them? There are tools (like `Solve`) that will get you answers to that kind of problem *much* more efficiently...

Comment: Inefficiency... well, it depends. Unless running out of memory, one may also consider difference between clarity and efficiency. Clarity is often a good starting point for small problems. In this case, I decided not to rewrite the starting point of using `Tuples`...

Comment: @kirma: In any case, `Sort[Join @@ 
  Permutations /@ Sqrt[IntegerPartitions[40, {3}, (Range@10)^2]]]` will answer the **a^2+b^2+c^2=40** kinds of question , again *vastly* more efficiently than building and filtering tuples.

Comment: I have employed `Solve` prior to using `Tuples`. However, I don't know how to arbitrarily specify the domain. Say, I want to constraint the domain to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11}.   
Also, computing cost isn't a problem. I'm using i7 4790K with 16GB memory.

Comment: @rasher let's say that I'd be really happy if there would be a mechanism that would be built specifically for "selecting tuples" explicitly, without generating them first.

Comment: @AbhijitGupta: Well, when you get  to domains beyond sizes a kid can do on an abacus (oh, say only 1-1000), let us know how that `Tuples[Range@1000,{3}]` works out for you ;-}   In any case, specification of domain/etc. is copiously covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If order does not matter you could use `IntegerPartition`. This yields 15 partitions.

```
ip = IntegerPartitions[15, {3}];
v = Pick[ip, Max@# < 11 & /@ ip]
```

yields:

```
{{10, 4, 1}, {10, 3, 2}, {9, 5, 1}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 3, 3}, {8, 6, 
  1}, {8, 5, 2}, {8, 4, 3}, {7, 7, 1}, {7, 6, 2}, {7, 5, 3}, {7, 4, 
  4}, {6, 6, 3}, {6, 5, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}
```

To count the permutations:

```
mn[x_] := Multinomial @@ Tally[x][[All, 2]]
Total[mn /@ v]
```

yields: 73 (as per `Tuples` answer).

To generate list:

```
Join @@ (Permutations /@ v)
```

Comment: Ah, lol - typing at same time - I'll happily delete mine if desired, +1 o/c! (and don't forget - there's another argument to IP to avoid the extra filtering step)

Comment: @rasher no your answer adds insight, so keep. :)